# What are these green rosettes popping up in my yard/

Tags: identification

We've found several of these on our lawn, under our oak tree. We are in Southern Ontario. What might it be?

[image]

Comment: Have you moved to this place in late fall or later? Curious if previous owners may have planted flower bulbs through the lawn for naturalizing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! No, we've been in this home for 18 years and nothing has been planted on lawn. Wondering if squirrels might have helped...  Hubby dug them up and composed them before mowing, but if I see more, I'll transfer one to a pot to see what happens. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The closest I can think of is *Veratrum*. It seems to be less ribbed than [*Veratrum viride*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veratrum_viride) (pictured below). In any case, Veratrum species are generally pretty toxic, so I'd recommend not eating it.  If your plant flowers, and look different to the flowers I've included here, please let me know.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yup this looks like your plant as well, J. Hosta or Plantain or Lily....monocot, yes?  Weird to be transplanted into the lawn however...squirrels?  Do they nab seed pods and plant them for later?  I recently learned squirrels only remember 25% of all their caches they bury for winter use.  This could be a bulb of an iris?

Comment: Not an Iris, I meant lily...arghhh.

Answer (score -1):

I came across 'Lady's Slipper' or Cypripedium macrothos.  See if this fits one of these plants...[Cypripedium macrothos][1

[Ladies Slipper](https://www4.uwsp.edu/biology/courses/plantid/cp-monocot/cp-monocot-140ladyslipper-d.htm)